# Would an airplane flying through superfluid helium experience lift and drag?

Tags: drag, superfluidity, lift

Would an airplane flying through superfluid helium experience lift and drag? The airplane is presumed cold enough to not heat up the helium.

Comment: shouldn't it be a boat? fluid ?

Comment: @annav  In general "boats," even submarines, have nonnegative buoyancy, while aircraft, even in liquid (remember, gas is a fluid too!) depend on dynamic lift.

Comment: Your vehicle could not have a power source. It couldn't have a combustion engine (or the helium would evaporate). Chemical reactions (for a battery) would be very sluggish (probably not at all). All that is left is the momentum it had when it entered the helium.

Comment: @LDC3: I think the question could be better formulated as placing a fuselage with wings in a fluid tunnel, in stead of a wind tunnel, where there is relative motion between the fluid and the fuselage and then measuring the lift and drag of the fuselage sustained from the fluid. That should resolve the problem of having to have an engine on the plane.

Comment: @LDC3 You could have a propeller blade rotated by a spring hidden inside the fuselage.

Answer (score 14):

Viscosity is necessary in order for the wing to generate lift. Without the change in circulation caused by flow separation from the trailing edge, there will be no lift. In an inviscid fluid there will be no separation, and hence no lift. A similar flow pattern can be observed in viscous fluids when the Reynolds number is extremely low (Re<<1), and you can see for yourself that there is a conspicuous absence of downwash behind the wing in this case.

[image]

$(Re<<1$, No Flow separation, $Lift=0)$

[image]

$(Re>>1$, Flow Separation, $Lift\not=0)$

So, based on my understanding of superfluids I think the flow pattern will be similar. Also, I believe an [experiment was done](http://thesis.library.caltech.edu/455/) with a micro-turbine in supercooled Helium in which the turbine produced near zero torque (implying that no lift was generated). So the answer to your question is, in principle, the plane should experience neither lift nor drag. However, I can imagine scenarios in which this would not be strictly true due to the non-ideal nature of real flows.

Comment: I'd love to see a citation for the superfluid turbine experiment you mention.

Comment: The included paper is the Ph.D thesis for Paul P. Craig of Caltech circa 1960, and (as a note of trivia) it turns out that one of the members of his thesis committee was none other than one Richard Feynman. Who knew!!!

Answer (score 0):

Superfluids have zero or near-zero viscosity so the drag is likely :-) to be near zero.  However, $lift$ is primarily due to conservation of momentum.  As the aircraft wing presumably has a nonzero angle of attack, it will be forcing helium atoms downwards, thus forcing the wing upwards.

Comment: Wrong. The flow will not be directed downwards in a flow with zero viscosity (see Kutta condition). A similar thing happens with creeping flow (Re<<1).

Comment: Ok, in a zero viscosity fluid, when I push a flat plate @ 45 degrees, where will the molecules go?  For that matter, there is rather a lot of disagreement about Kutta. E.g.  http://secretofflight.wordpress.com/why-kz-is-incorrect/

Comment: I know it seems counter-intuitive because we rarely see this type of thing happening at everyday Reynolds numbers, but it's true. The shape of a 747 will not make lift if it were moving through honey, it just won't. It's the same reason why sharks and dolphins have fins to propel themselves but bacteria must use a flagellum or corkscrew type of method. No separation = no lift.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: In a superfluid the molecules will first go down and then up producing exactly zero net lift. (see the image in Bryson's answer). But it turns out that real superfluids aren't theoretical superfluids. They always have a real part so they can impart lift - just very, very weak.

Comment: @slebetman  Thanks for the detailed info. I always like to learn new stuff.

Comment: @BrysonS.: If the authors of papers about friction and the Kutta condition would had cared to include inertial forces, they would had realized that friction is **not** needed to produce lift once the Reynolds number is sufficiently large. And in superfluid helium it will be at almost any speed.

Comment: @PeterKämpf I could not disagree more. Even in the limit of infinite Reynolds number, you are still assuming a flow which leaves the airfoil smoothly (i.e. stagnation point at the trailing edge). This requires both a bound vortex around the airfoil and a starting vortex. Neither of these is possible without the effects of friction. Kelvin's Theorems can be used to support this argument.

Comment: @BrysonS. Good joke. Kelvin's theorem is only valid in inviscid flow.

Comment: @PeterKämpf That's exactly my point. If you want the time-derivative of circulation to be non-zero (as you would need to generate lift) you MUST include  viscous stresses in the fluid. If you do not, Kelvin's Theorem tells us that the circulation must forever remain constant.

Comment: @BrysonS. That is what the starting vortex is for. By the way, Kelvin just translated the Helmholtz theorems into English, so it would be more appropriate to talk of the Helmholtz theorems. They (the second and third) might help you in improving your understanding of potential flow in the absence of friction. Now wipe the egg off your face and move on.

Comment: @PeterKämpf This will have to be my last post because we both have better things to do, but what I am suggesting is that there would be no starting vortex (and hence no bound vortex) without viscosity. I remain entirely open to hearing your explanation as to how the starting vortex (and its associated vorticity) is generated if viscosity is not responsible. Again, you agree that circulation is a conserved quantity in an inviscid flow, yet you also agree that the circulation around a lifting airfoil can (and does) change with time. How do you square these seemingly incongruous observations?

Comment: @BrysonS. To make it as simple as possible, just look at a hypothetical hypersonic flow with no friction, but inertial forces. This extreme case should help: Lift is possible without friction.

Comment: @BrysonS. - This is an exceptional case, but what if the speed of the aircraft was hypersonic (speed of sound related to the fluid)? I'm assuming a case where a fluid would have zero viscosity, but the fluid would not be incompressible, so that there would be a finite speed of sound. In the hypersonic case, most of the lift is due to molecules bouncing off the bottom, in the form of the pattern of shock waves produced above and below a wing.

Comment: Agreed. Everything in the proceeding line of thought applies to subsonic lift generation only. Because the mechanism of lift generation is fundamentally different for supersonic flows, no Kutta condition-like requirement is necessary.

Comment: @slebetman: You say "the molecules will first go down and then up producing exactly zero net lift". Will that then produce a torque?

Comment: This is wrong. The surface integral of the pressure of the incompressible, inviscid and irrotational steady flow is zero as shown in D'Alembert's paradox https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_paradox.

Comment: @Hans In a theoretical superfluid I believe the torque would be zero as well. Nothing to drag/pull on your surfaces so no forces imparted. Again, as I mentioned, real-world superfluid aren't the same as theory

Comment: @slebetman: That is wrong. The net force which is the total surface integration of the pressure is zero. However, the pressure at each surface point is not all zero. Unless the surface is completely symmetric with respect to the direction of in incoming flow, there bound to be a nonzero torque.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably superfluid is still largely incompressible under small pressure, so it obeys [Bernoulli's principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_principle). With the normal shape of the wing, it will still generate lifts due to the pressure difference between the top and bottom wing surfaces.

---

Edit: I was wrong above. If the superfluid is inviscid and irrotational, the [D'Alembert's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_paradox) states that the net force is zero. However, the plane is in three dimension, there will be vortices spilling from the tips of the wing. The flow is thus rotational, violating the premise of D'Alembert's paradox. There will be induced lift and drag. A phenomenological theory called [Prandtl's lift-line theory](https://web.stanford.edu/~cantwell/AA200_Course_Material/AA200_Course_Notes/AA200_Ch_12_Wings_of_Finite_Span_Cantwell.pdf) can be used to compute the net force induced by the vortices.

Comment: Is this the infamous simple and wrong airplane explanation?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using Bernoulli's principle to relate pressure to velocity. The reason this principle is commonly abused is because a spurious explanation is given for why the velocity is higher in one area versus another...

Comment: @BrysonS.: I have corrected my answer. Please review.